# What is `git restore` and how is it different from `git reset`?

Tags: git, restore, git-reset, unstage

When I want to unstage a staged file, all of my Git tutorials show something like:

```
$ git add *
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    README.md -> README
    modified:   CONTRIBUTING.md
```

This hint tells us to use `git reset` for unstaging a staged file.

But instead, in my terminal, I see:

```
git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    renamed:    cat.js -> catcat.js
    renamed:    tolendo.gogo -> tolendo.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    readme (copy).md
    tolendo (copy).txt
    zing (copy).html
```

My terminal tells me to use `git restore --staged` but the tutorials, as well as [Git’s website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things#_unstaging), tell me to use `git reset HEAD`.

I have no idea about the new `restore` command. I tried Google to find the difference between `git reset` and `git restore` but nothing seemed to fit my question.

Comment: did you check this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History  ?

Comment: I'm reading this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things

and as I said above, in there, git shows the reset command, but in my computer, it shows the restore command, 

So, I wonder what is the difference about them,

I googled some links, but they are too vague, that's why I brought here to get a clear answer.

Comment: `git restore` is introduced in 2.23.0 (with `git switch`). To unstage a file, `git reset HEAD <file>` and `git restore --staged <file>` are the same. For the other differences, see the manual https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore.

Comment: Thank @ElpieKay

one more tiny question: why you guys don't answer instead of comment?

I'm new here so just wonder, tks

Comment: Because I can't give you a complete answer to your question. Instead, a comment may provide some clues and help you find it out.

Comment: Another example of the adulterated mess that is called git. Why not a simple "git revert"? Now there are three git options: restore, reset and revert, with nuanced differences between them

Comment: @Paul basically every mature software project has that problem. Either you keep legacy commands and innovate on the side, or you break everything that was based on the original, now flawed design. You simply can't design something ideally.

Comment: potentially somebody could come up with another git subcommand providing already existing functionality in order to confuse normal thinking people even more

Comment: And @Paul reading `man git` which has a specific section on these three, will not illuminate you because the terminology used is ambiguous and the statements literally contradict each other.

Comment: @user12411795 I'm sure they're planning more of that for future versions ...

Comment: If you get upset with `man git` please try https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/ :-)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I have presented `git restore` (which is still marked as "experimental") in "[How to reset all files from working directory but not from staging area?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)", with the recent Git 2.23 (August 2019).

It helps separate `git checkout` into two commands:

- one for files ([`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)), which can cover `git reset` cases.
- one for branches ([`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), as seen in "[Confused by git checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)"), which deals only with branches, not files.

As [reset, restore and revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_reset_restore_and_revert) documentation states:

> There are three commands with similar names: `git reset`, `git restore` and `git revert`.
>
> - `git-revert` is about making a new commit that reverts the changes made by other commits.
> - `git-restore` is about restoring files in the working tree from either the index or another commit.
>     This command does not update your branch.
>     The command can also be used to restore files in the index from another commit.
> - `git-reset` is about updating your branch, moving the tip in order to add or remove commits from the branch. This operation changes the commit history.
>     `git reset` can also be used to restore the index, overlapping with `git restore`.

So:

> To restore a file in the index to match the version in HEAD (this is the same as using `git-reset`)
>
> ```
> git restore --staged hello.c
> ```
>
> or you can restore both the index and the working tree (this the same as using `git-checkout`)
>
> ```
> git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree hello.c
> ```
>
> or the short form which is more practical but less readable:
>
> ```
> git restore -s@ -SW hello.c
> ```

---

With Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020), "`git restore --staged`" did not correctly update the cache-tree structure, resulting in bogus trees to be written afterwards, which has been corrected.

See [discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/20200108104008.GA2207365@coredump.intra.peff.net/).

See [commit e701bab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e701bab3e95f7029e59717eab610a544821b2213) (08 Jan 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 09e393d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09e393d913072d7765b02aba1210d843a83cfbae), 22 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`restore`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e701bab3e95f7029e59717eab610a544821b2213): invalidate cache-tree when removing entries with --staged
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Torsten Krah</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> When "[`git restore --staged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt---staged) " removes a path that's in the index, it marks the entry with `CE_REMOVE,` but we don't do anything to invalidate the cache-tree.
>   In the non-staged case, we end up in `checkout_worktree()`, which calls `remove_marked_cache_entries()`. That actually drops the entries from the index, as well as invalidating the cache-tree and untracked-cache.
>
> But with `--staged`, we never call `checkout_worktree()`, and the `CE_REMOVE` entries remain. Interestingly, they are dropped when we write out the index, but that means the resulting index is inconsistent: its cache-tree will not match the actual entries, and running "`git commit`" immediately after will create the wrong tree.
>
> We can solve this by calling `remove_marked_cache_entries()` ourselves before writing out the index. Note that we can't just hoist it out of `checkout_worktree()`; that function needs to iterate over the `CE_REMOVE` entries (to drop their matching worktree files) before removing them.
>
> One curiosity about the test: without this patch, it actually triggers a BUG() when running git-restore:
>
> ```
> BUG: cache-tree.c:810: new1 with flags 0x4420000 should not be in cache-tree
> ```
>
> But in the original problem report, which used a similar recipe, [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) actually creates the bogus index (and the commit is created with the wrong tree). I'm not sure why the test here behaves differently than my out-of-suite reproduction, but what's here should catch either symptom (and the fix corrects both cases).

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git restore --staged --worktree`" **now defaults to take the contents out of "HEAD"**, instead of erring out.

See [commit 088018e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/088018e34d705aad696acfeb624cfe5552ba256f) (05 May 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4c2941a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c2941a5fa6c99cb204c48d2fe6f3b55a7211012), 08 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`restore`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/088018e34d705aad696acfeb624cfe5552ba256f): default to HEAD when combining --staged and --worktree
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
>   <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
>
> By default, files are restored from the index for `--worktree`, and from HEAD for `--staged`.
>
> When `--worktree` and `--staged` are combined, `--source` must be specified to disambiguate the restore source, thus making it cumbersome to restore a file in both the worktree and the index.
>
> (Due to an oversight, the `--source` requirement, though documented, is not actually enforced.)
>
> However, HEAD is also a reasonable default for `--worktree` when combined with `--staged`, so make it the default anytime `--staged` is used (whether combined with `--worktree` or not).

So now, this works:

```
git restore --staged --worktree
git restore -SW
```

Comment: As of git version 2.29.2, "THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE." for `git restore` at the end of DESCRIPTION section.

Comment: @IvanChau Don't worry, those commands are not going anywhere and won't change drastically. You can use them. See https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq4kor6g8z.fsf@gitster.c.googlers.com/

Comment: I would advise a user of `git restore --staged` to never make the mistake of running `git restore --staged *` (or with any wild-card matching) in a naive attempt to simply remove the currently staged files from the staging area. What this actually does for me with git version 2.27.0 is `git rm` every file committed in my repository.

Comment: Can you explain why `git restore *` throws errors about files not in git but `git restore '*'` works as expected?  This makes no sense to me.  Is it a bug?

Comment: @BrianVPS I never use `'*'` or `*` in Git commands: the star is interpreted by the shell and expanded in ways that does not always work with the Git command. It is best to simply mention the folder from where you want the restore to apply: `git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree -- .`: the trailing `-- .` will specify the current folder as the one where the restore takes place.

Comment: @VonC a quoted star (`'*'`, `"*"` or escaped as `\*` [posix]) should not be expanded by the shell but passed as argument to git, so then left for interpretation by git - not the shell. For [glob-star resolution with git pathspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-glob), honestly no idea if and how they apply with `git-restore`. But that is independent from shell which comes first. Now as git is verbose about the new commands I'd sometimes like to take a retrospective on the old ones but perhaps need to install an old version to see them (the old msgs) again.

Comment: @hakre I agree. Still, I would avoid `*` and use `.` instead.

Comment: @VonC good advice on `.` and also just the name of the subdirectory (or blank for the whole tree). Just learned about [`set -f`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion), next is just to prevent filenames in git repositories starting with a dash `-` ... ;)

Answer (score 139):

To add to [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003889/1256452), and bring into the picture all the relevant commands, in alphabetical order, I will cover:

- `git checkout`
- `git reset`
- `git restore`
- `git switch`

I'll throw in one more, the misnamed `git revert`, as well.

#### From an end-user perspective

All you *need* are `git checkout`, `git reset`, and `git revert`.  These commands have been in Git all along.

But `git checkout` has, in effect, two *modes of operation*.  One mode is "safe": it won't accidentally destroy any unsaved work.  The other mode is "unsafe": if you use it, and it tells Git to wipe out some unsaved file, Git assumes that (a) you knew it meant that and (b) you really did mean to wipe out your unsaved file, so Git immediately wipes out your unsaved file.

This is not very friendly, so the Git folks finally—after years of users griping—split `git checkout` into two new commands.  This leads us to:

#### From a historical perspective

`git restore` is *new*, having first come into existence in August 2019, in Git 2.23.  `git reset` is very old, having been in Git all along, dating back to before 2005.  Both commands have the ability to destroy unsaved work.

The `git switch` command is also new, introduced along with `git restore` in Git 2.23.  It implements the "safe half" of `git checkout`; `git restore` implements the "unsafe half".

#### When would you use which command?

This is the most complicated part, and to really understand it, we need to know the following items:

- Git is really all about *commits*.  Commits get stored *in* the Git repository.  The `git push` and `git fetch` commands transfer *commits*—whole commits, as an all-or-nothing deal<sup>1</sup>—to the other Git.  You either have all of a commit, or you don't have it.  Other commands, such as `git merge` or `git rebase`, all work with *local* commits.  The `pull` command runs `fetch` (to get commits) followed by a second command to work with the commits once they're local.
- New commits *add to the repository*.  You almost never *remove* a commit *from* the repository.  Only one of the five commands listed here—checkout, reset, restore, revert, and switch—is capable of removing commits.<sup>2</sup>
- Each commit is numbered by its *hash ID*, which is unique to that one particular commit.  It's actually computed from what's *in* the commit, which is how Git makes these numbers work across all Gits eveywhere.  This means that what is in the commit is frozen for all time: if you change anything, what you get is a new commit with a new number, and the old commit is still there, with its same old number.
- Each commit stores two things: a snapshot, and metadata.  The metadata include the hash ID(s) of some previous commit(s).  This makes commits form backwards-looking chains.
- A *branch name* holds the hash ID of one commit.  This makes the branch name *find* that commit, which in turn means two things:

  - that particular commit is the *tip commit* of that branch; and
  - all commits leading up to and including that tip commit are *on* that branch.
- We're also going to talk about Git's *index* in a moment, and your *working tree*.  They're separate from these but worth mentioning early, especially since the index has three names: Git sometimes calls it the *index*, sometimes calls it the *staging area*, and sometimes—rarely these days—calls it the *cache*.  All three names refer to the same thing.

Everything up through the *branch name* is, I think, best understood via pictures (at least for most people).  If we draw a series of commits, with newer commits towards the right, using `o` for each commit and omitting some commits for space or whatever, we get something like this:

```
        o--o---o   <-- feature-top
       /        \
o--o--o--o--...--o---o--o   <-- main
    \               /
     o--o--...--o--o   <-- feature-hull
```

which, as you can see, is a boat repository.   There are three branches.  The mainline branch holds *every commit*, including all the commits on the top row and bottom (hull) row.  The `feature-top` branch holds the top three commits and also the three commits along the main line to the left, but not any of the commits on the bottom row.  All the connectors *between* commits are—well, *should be* but I don't have a good enough font—one-way arrows, pointing left, or down-and-left, or up-and-left.

These "arrows", or one way connections from commit to commit, are technically [*arcs*, or one-way edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31208), in a [*directed graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).  This directed graph is one without cycles, making it a Directed Acyclic Graph or [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), which has a bunch of properties that are useful to Git.

If you're just using Git to store files inside commits, all you really care about are the round `o` [*nodes* or *vertices* (again two words for the same thing)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1441525), each of which acts to store your files, but you should at least be vaguely aware of how they are arranged.  It matters, especially because of *merges*.  Merge commits are those with two outgoing arcs, pointing backwards to two of what Git calls *parent commits*.  The child commit is the one "later": just as human parents are always older than their children, Git parent commits are older than their children.

We need one more thing, though: **Where do new commits come from?**  We noted that what's in a commit—both the snapshot, holding all the files, and the metadata, holding the rest of the information Git keeps about a commit—is all read-only.  Your files are not only frozen, they're also *transformed*, and the transformed data are then *de-duplicated*, so that even though every commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, the repository itself stays relatively slim.  But this means that the files *in* a commit can only be *read* by Git, and *nothing*—not even Git itself—can *write* to them.  They get saved once, and are de-duplicated from then on.  The commits act as archives, almost like tar or rar or winzip or whatever.

To work with a Git repository, then, we have to have Git *extract* the files.  This takes the files *out* of some commit, turning those special archive-formatted things into regular, usable files.  Note that Git may well be able to store files that your computer literally *can't* store: a classic example is a file named `aux.h`, for some C program, on a Windows machine.  We won't go into all the details, but it is theoretically possible to still get work done with this repository, which was probably built on a Linux system, even if you're on a Windows system where you can't work with the `aux.h` file directly.

Anyway, assuming there are no nasty little surprises like `aux.h`, you would just run `git checkout` or `git switch` to get some commit *out* of Git.  This will fill in your *working tree*, populating it from the files stored in the *tip commit* of some branch.  The *tip commit* is, again, the *last* commit on that branch, as found by the *branch name*.  Your `git checkout` or `git switch` selected that commit to be the *current commit*, by selecting that branch name to be the *current branch*.  You now have all the files *from* that commit, in an area where you can see them and work on them: your *working tree*.

Note that the files in your working tree *are not actually in Git itself*.  They were just *extracted from* Git.  This matters a lot, because when `git checkout` extracts the files *from* Git, it actually puts each file in two places.  One of those places is the ordinary everyday file you see and work on / with.  The other place Git puts each file is into Git's *index*.

As I mentioned a moment ago, the index has three names: index, staging area, and cache.  All refer to the same thing: the place Git sticks these "copies" of each file.  Each one is actually pre-de-duplicated, so the word "copy" is slightly wrong, but—unlike much of the rest of its innards—Git actually does a really good job of hiding the de-duplication aspect.  Unless you start getting into internal commands like `git ls-files` and `git update-index`, you don't need to know about this part, and can just think of the index as holding a copy of the file, ready to go into the *next commit*.

What this all means for you as someone just *using* Git is that the index / staging-area acts as your *proposed next commit*.  When you run `git commit`, Git is going to package up *these* copies of the file as the ones to be archived in the snapshot.  The copies you have in your working tree are *yours;* the *index / staging-area* copies are *Git's*, ready to go.  So, if you *change* your copies and want the *changed* copy to be what goes in the next snapshot, you must tell Git: *Update the Git copy, in the Git index / staging-area.*  You do this with `git add`.<sup>3</sup>  The `git add` command means *make the proposed-next-commit copy match the working-tree copy*.  It's the `add` command that does the updating: this is when Git compresses and de-duplicates the file and makes it ready for archiving, not at `git commit` time.<sup>4</sup>

Then, assuming you have some series of commits ending with the one with *`hash-N`:*

```
[hash1] <-[hash2] ... <-[hashN]   <--branch
```

you run `git commit`, give it any metadata it needs (a commit log message), and you get an N+1'th commit:

```
[hash1] <-[hash2] ... <-[hashN] <-[hashN+1]   <--branch
```

Git automatically updates the *branch name* to point to the *new commit*, which has therefore been *added to the branch*.

Let's look at each of the various commands now:

- `git checkout`: this is a large and complicated command.

  We already saw this one, or at least, *half* of this one.  We used it to pick out a branch name, and therefore a particular commit.  This kind of checkout first looks at our current commit, index, and working tree.  It makes sure that we have committed all our modified files, or—this part gets a bit complicated—that if we *haven't* committed all our modified files, switching to that other branch is "safe".  If it's *not* safe, `git checkout` tells you that you can't switch due to having modified files.  If it *is* safe, `git checkout` will switch; if you didn't mean to switch, you can just switch back.  (See also [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452))

  But `git checkout` has an *unsafe* half.  Suppose you have modified some file in your working tree, such as `README.md` or `aux.h` or whatever.  You now look back at what you changed and think: *No, that's a bad idea.  I should get rid of this change.  I'd like the file back exactly as it was before.*

  To get this—to *wipe out* your changes to, say, `README.md`—you can run:

  ```
  git checkout -- README.md
  ```

  The `--` part here is optional.  It's a good idea to use it, because it tells Git that the part that comes after `--` is a *file name*, not a *branch name*.

  Suppose you have a *branch* named `hello` *and* a *file* named `hello`.  What does:

  ```
  git checkout hello
  ```

  mean?  Are we asking Git to clobber the *file* `hello` to remove the changes we made, or are we asking Git to check out the *branch* `hello`?  To make this unambiguous, you have to write either:

  ```
  git checkout -- hello        (clobber the file)
  ```

  or:

  ```
  git checkout hello --        (get the branch)
  ```

  This case, where there are branches and files or directories with the same name, is a particularly insidious one.  It has bitten real users.  It's *why* `git switch` exists now.  The `git switch` command *never means clobber my files*.  It only means *do the safe kind of `git checkout`.*

  (The `git checkout` command has been smartened up too, so that if you have the new commands and you run the "bad" kind of ambiguous `git checkout`, Git will just complain at you and do nothing at all.  Either use the smarter split-up commands, or add the `--` at the right place to pick which kind of operation you want.)

  More precisely, *this kind* of `git checkout`, ideally spelled `git checkout -- paths`, is a request for Git to copy files from Git's index to your working tree.  This means *clobber my files*.  You can also run `git checkout tree-ish -- paths`, where you add a commit hash ID<sup>5</sup> to the command.  This tells Git to copy the files from that commit, first to Git's index, and then on to your working tree.  This, too, means *clobber my files:* the difference is where Git gets the copies of the files it's extracting.

  If you ran `git add` on some file and thus copied it into Git's index, you need `git checkout HEAD -- file` to get it back from the current commit.  The copy that's in Git's *index* is the one you `git add`-ed.  So these two forms of `git checkout`, with a commit hash ID (or the name `HEAD`), the optional `--`, and the file name, are the unsafe *clobber my files* forms.
- `git reset`: this is also a large and complicated command.

  There are, depending on how you count, up to about five or six different forms of `git reset`.  We'll concentrate on a smaller subset here.

  - `git reset [ --hard | --mixed | --soft ] [ commit ]`

    Here, we're asking Git to do several things.  First, if we give a *`commit`* argument, such as `HEAD` or `HEAD~3` or some such, we've picked a particular *commit* that Git should *reset to*.  This is the kind of command that will *remove commits* by ejecting them off the end of the branch.  Of all the commands listed here, this is the only one that removes any commits.  One other command—`git commit --amend`—has the effect of ejecting the *last* commit while putting on a new replacement, but that one is limited to ejecting *one* commit.

    Let's show this as a drawing.  Suppose we have:

    ```
    ...--E--F--G--H   <-- branch
    ```

    That is, this branch, named `branch`, ends with four commits whose hash IDs we'll call `E`, `F`, `G`, and `H` in that order.  The name `branch` currently stores the hash ID of the last of these commits, `H`.  If we use `git reset --hard HEAD~3`, we're telling Git to eject the *last three commits*.  The result is:

    ```
           F--G--H   ???
          /
    ...--E   <-- branch
    ```

    The name `branch` now selects commit `E`, not commit `H`.  If we did not write down (on paper, on a whiteboard, in a file) the hash IDs of the last three commits, they've just become somewhat hard to find.  Git does gives a way to find them again, for a while, but mostly they just seem to be *gone*.

    The `HEAD~3` part of this command is how we chose to drop the last three commits.  It's part of a whole sub-topic in Git, documented in [the gitrevisions manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), on ways to name specific commits.  The reset command just needs the hash ID of an actual commit, or anything equivalent, and `HEAD~3` means *go back three first-parent steps*, which in this case gets us from commit `H` back to commit `E`.

    The `--hard` part of the `git reset` is how we tell Git what to do with (a) its index and (b) our working tree files.  We have three choices here:

    - `--soft` tells Git: *leave both alone*.  Git will move the *branch name* without touching the index or our working tree.  If you run `git commit` now, whatever is (still) in the index is what goes into the *new* commit.  If the index matches the snapshot in commit `H`, this gets you a new commit whose *snapshot* is `H`, but whose *parent* is `E`, as if commits `F` through `H` had all been collapsed into a single new commit.  People usually call this *squashing*.
    - `--mixed` tells Git: *reset your index, but leave my working tree alone*.  Git will move the branch name, then *replace every file that is in the index with the one from the newly selected commit*.  But Git will leave all your *working tree* files alone.  This means that as far as Git is concerned, you can start `git add`ing files to make a new commit.  Your new commit won't match `H` unless you `git add` *everything*, so this means you could, for instance, build a new intermediate commit, sort of like `E+F` or something, if you wanted.
    - `--hard` tells Git: *reset your index **and** my working tree.*  Git will move the branch name, replace all the files in its index, and replace all the files in your working tree, all as one big thing.  It's now as if you never made those three commits at all.  You no longer have the files from `F`, or `G`, or `H`: you have the files from commit `E`.

    Note that if you leave out the *`commit`* part of this kind of (hard/soft/mixed) `reset`, Git will use `HEAD`.  Since `HEAD` names the *current commit* (as selected by the current branch name), this leaves the branch name itself unchanged: it still selects the same commit as before.  So this is only useful with `--mixed` or `--hard`, because `git reset --soft`, with no commit hash ID, means *don't move the branch name, don't change Git's index, and don't touch my working tree*.  Those are the three things this kind of `git reset` can do—move the branch name, change what's in Git's index, and change what's in your working tree—and you just ruled all three out.  Git is OK with doing nothing, but why bother?
  - `git reset [ tree-ish ] -- path`

    This is the other kind of `git reset` we'll care about here.  It's a bit like a mixed reset, in that it means *clobber some of the index copies of files*, but here you specify *which files to clobber*.  It's also a bit *unlike* a mixed reset, because this kind of `git reset` will never move the branch name.

    Instead, you pick which files you want copied from somewhere.  The *somewhere* is the *`tree-ish`* you give; if you don't give one, the *somewhere* is `HEAD`, i.e., the current commit.  This can only restore files in the *proposed next commit* to the form they have in *some existing commit*.  By defaulting to the *current* existing commit, this kind of `git reset -- path` has the effect of undoing a `git add -- path`.<sup>6</sup>

    There are several other forms of `git reset`.  To see what they all mean, consult [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).
- `git restore`: this got split off from `git checkout`.

  Basically, this does the same thing as the various forms of `git checkout` and `git reset` that clobber files (in your working tree and/or in Git's index).  It's *smarter* than the old `git checkout`-and-clobber-my-work variant, in that you get to choose where the files come from *and* where they go, all in the one command line.

  To do what you used to do with `git checkout -- file`, you just run `git restore --staged --worktree -- file`.  (You can leave out the `--` part, as with `git checkout`, in most cases, but it's just generally wise to get in the habit of using it.  Like `git add`, this command is designed such that only files named `-whatever` are actually problematic.)

  To do what you used to do with `git reset -- file`, you just run `git restore --staged -- file`.  That is, you tell `git restore` to copy from `HEAD` to staging area / index, which is how `git reset` operates.

  Note that you can copy a file from some existing commit, to Git's index, without touching your working tree copy of that file: `git restore --source commit --staged -- file` does that.  You can't do that at all with the old `git checkout` but you *can* do that with the old `git reset`, as `git reset commit -- file`.  And, you can copy a file from some existing commit, to your working tree, without touching the staged copy: `git restore --source commit --worktree -- file` does that.  The overlapping part (restore and reset) exists *because* `git restore` is new, and this kind of restore makes sense; probably, ideally, we should always use `git restore` here, instead of using the old `git reset` way of doing things, but Git tries to maintain backwards compatibility.

  The new ability—to copy from any arbitrary source, to your working tree, without touching Git's index / staging-area copy—is just that: new.  You couldn't do it before.  (You could run `git show commit:path > path`, before, but that falls outside our five commands to examine.)
- `git switch`: this just does the "safe half" of `git checkout`.  That's really all you need to know.  Using `git switch`, without `--force`, Git won't overwrite your unsaved work, even if you make a typo or whatever.  The old `git checkout` command could overwrite unsaved work: if your typo turns a branch name into a file name, for instance, well, oops.
- `git revert` (I added this for completeness): this makes a *new commit*.  The point of the new commit is to *back out* what someone did in some existing commit.  You therefore need to name the existing commit that revert should back out.  This command probably should have been named `git backout`.

  If you back out the most recent commit, this does revert to the second-most-recent snapshot:

  ```
    ...--G--H   <-- branch
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
    ...--G--H--Ħ   <-- branch
  ```

  where commit `Ħ` (H-bar) "undoes" commit `H` and therefore leaves us with the same *files* as commit `G`.  But we don't have to undo the *most recent* commit.  We could take:

  ```
    ...--E--F--G--H   <-- branch
  ```

  and add a commit `Ǝ` that undoes `E` to get:

  ```
    ...--E--F--G--H--Ǝ   <-- branch
  ```

  which may not match the source snapshot of any previous commit!

---

<sup>1</sup>Git is, slowly, growing a facility to "partly get" a commit so that you can deal with huge repositories with huge commits without having to wait for the entire commit all at once, for instance.  Right now that's not something ordinary users will ever see, and when it does come to regular users, it's meant as an add-on to the basic "all or nothing" mode of a commit.  It will turn this from "you either have a commit, or not" to "you have a commit—either all of it, or part of it with the promise to deliver the rest soon—or not; if you have part of a commit, you can work with the part, but that's all".

<sup>2</sup>Even then, a "removed" commit is not *gone* yet: you can get it back.  This answer won't cover how to do that, though.  Also, `git commit --amend` is a special case, which we will mention, but not really cover properly here.

<sup>3</sup>To remove the file from both your working tree *and* Git's index, you can use `git rm`.  If you remove the file from your working tree, then run `git add` on that file name, Git will "add" the removal, so that works too.

<sup>4</sup>If you use `git commit -a`, Git will, at that time, run `git add` on all the files.  This is done in a tricky way that can break some poorly-written pre-commit hooks.  I recommend learning the two step process, in part because of those poorly-written hooks—though I'd try to avoid or fix them if possible—and in part just because if *you* try to avoid learning about Git's index like the authors of those poorly-written hooks did, Git is going to give you more trouble later.

<sup>5</sup>The reason this is a *tree-ish* and not a *commit-ish* is that you can use anything that specifies some existing internal Git *tree* object.  Each commit has a saved snapshot, though, that is suitable for here, and is what you'd normally put here.

<sup>6</sup>As with all these other Git commands, you *can* use the `--` between the `add` command and the paths to add.  It's actually a good habit to get into, as this means that you can add a path named `-u`, if you have such a path: `git add -- -u` means *add the file named `-u`* but `git add -u` doesn't mean that at all.  Of course, files whose names match option sequences are less common and less surprising than files whose names match branch names: it's really easy to have a `dev` branch *and* a set of files named `dev/whatever`.  Since file paths will match using directories, for add, checkout, reset, and restore, these can get mixed up.  The `add` command doesn't take a *branch name* though, so it's safer in that respect.

Comment: Really appreciate the efforts of writing such a detailed answer!

Comment: Some controversy about whether "thank yous" are appropriate on SO or just wasting other's time (so should be used sparingly), but thank you. Great answer! (I don't say without real merit - you've consolidated a lot of info scattered in far too many other places)

Comment: @Larry: as a general rule, the questions and answers shouldn't have "fluffy" bits like that, but comments can (though long comment threads sometimes get stripped off).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.
Since as you say the git folks split `checkout` into `switch` and `restore` could you add a bit on how to do `git checkout <tag>` using switch/restore`??

Comment: @Rusi: the `git switch` equivalent of `git checkout <tag>` is simply `git switch --detach <tag>`. The switch command requires the `--detach` flag from you, so that you acknowledge that you understand the result is a detached HEAD.

Comment: The best discussion/description/explanation of Git I've ever read. Congratulations, and thanks!

Comment: This is more than just an answer to the question asked...but in this case I don't mind. Very informative.

Comment: I learned more about Git from this one answer than I have in two years of online reading/training.  @torek, I’ve since looked at more of your answers, and all that I’ve seen are similarly superlative.  I wish you would write a book. Outside of that, are there any learning resources you can recommend? I’m asking you, torek, in particular because I’d be thrilled to find something that explains git as lucidly as you do—maybe you learned from someone else.

Answer (score 34):

**For your 1st question "What is git-restore?":**

git-restore is a tool to revert non-commited changes. Non-commited changes are: a) changes in your working copy, or b) content in your index (a.k.a. staging area).

This command was introduced in git 2.23 (together with the git-switch) to separate multiple concerns previously united in git-checkout.

git-restore can be used in three different modes, depending on whether you like to revert work in the working copy, in the index, or both.

`git restore [--worktree] <file>` overwrites <file> in your working copy with the contents in your index (*). In other words, it reverts your changes in the working copy. Whether you specify `--worktree` or not does not matter because it is implied if you don't say otherwise.

`git restore --staged <file>` overwrites <file> in your index with the current HEAD from the local repository. In other words, it unstages previously staged content. In so far, it is indeed equivalent to the old `git reset HEAD <file>`.

To overwrite both, the working copy and the index with the current HEAD, use `git restore --staged --worktree --source HEAD <file>`. This version does both: revert your working copy to HEAD and unstage previously staged work.

**For your 2nd question "What's the difference between git-restore and git-reset?":**

There are overlaps between these two commands, and differences.

Both can be used to modify your working copy and/or the staging area. However, only git-reset can modify your repository. In this sense, git-restore seems the safer option if you only want to revert local work.

There are more differences, which I can't enumerate here.

(*) A file not `add`ed to the index is still regarded to be in the index, however in it's "clean" state from the current HEAD revision.

Answer (score 8):

A drawing as a quick reference may be helpful (*arrows represent updating place and source*):




[image: git restore reference diagram]





Note that these `git` commands also need other parameters, such as a `path`.
Examples:

```
git restore . 
git add .
git commit -m "commit name here"
git restore --staged .
```

This is not a direct answer to OP's question, rather about `restore` part, since search results of `git restore` directs to here. `reset` part is already explained in other answers.

Answer (score -2):

**git reset -- :**

```
   This command is used to unstaged changes that were previously added to the 
   staging area.

  The <mode> parameter specifies the reset mode. The commonly used modes for 
  unstaging are mixed, soft, and hard.

  mixed (default): Unstages changes but keeps them in the working directory. It 
 resets the index to match the HEAD commit.

  soft: Unstages changes and keeps them in the index (staging area). It does 
  not modify the working directory.

  hard: Unstages changes and discards them both from the index and the working 
  directory.
  <file> specifies the file or files you want to unstage.
Example usage:

# Unstage changes and keep them in the working directory
git reset <file>

# Unstage changes and keep them in the index (staging area)
git reset --soft <file>

# Unstage changes and discard them from both index and working directory
git reset --hard <file>

**git restore --staged <file>:**

This command is used to unstaged changes from the index (staging area) and revert them to the state of the last commit.
It does not modify the working directory; it only affects the staging area.
<file> specifies the file you want to unstage.
```

Example usage:

```
# Unstage changes from the index (staging area)
git restore --staged <file>
In summary, both git reset --<mode> <file> and git restore --staged <file> can be used to unstage changes, but the key differences are:

git reset has more flexibility in terms of the reset mode (mixed, soft, hard), which determines what happens to the changes in the working directory.

git restore --staged is focused specifically on unstaging changes from the index while keeping the working directory unchanged.

You can choose the appropriate command based on your desired outcome: whether you want to unstage changes while preserving them in the working directory, or unstage changes solely from the index/staging area.
```