# What is the difference between git restore --staged some-file and git checkout -- some-file?

Tags: git

I am exploring the possible options to undo something that has been done with git. I came across this [post](https://devconnected.com/how-to-undo-git-add-command/) and I see that there are 3 options `git reset`, `git checkout` and `git restore`.

I think I sort of understand what git reset does (not entirely but I think that's a separate question), however I don't understand what difference is there in running `git checkout -- some_file` and `git restore --staged some_file`

Is there a difference in how the two commands change the files in the working directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the \`git restore\` command and what is the difference between \`git restore\` and \`git reset\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003030/what-is-the-git-restore-command-and-what-is-the-difference-between-git-restor)

Comment: That's a very useful link and I am going to take a more in-depth look, but it doesn't really explain how git checkout is different from those.

Comment: @djvaroli: it does (explain the difference), especially if you read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66309040/1256452). It is rather long but I think it's worth reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize Torek's answer:

- [`git checkout -- somefile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) overwrite working tree with the contents in the index
- [`git restore --staged -- somefile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--W) restore the index content from HEAD for that file (the old `git reset -- file`, typically used to unstage a modified file added by error)

Torek insists on the fact `git restore --source <aCommit> --worktree -- somefile` is new (cannot be done with checkout): the ability to restore a file in the working tree *without touching the index*.

---

[Darren Ng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8243991/darren-ng) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465810/what-is-the-difference-between-git-restore-staged-some-file-and-git-checkout#comment121375292_66470532):

> Now I can discard staged changes with a `single git restore --staged --worktree -- FILE`, instead of 2-step `git restore --staged FILE`+`git checkout FILE`.

True, but Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) makes it clear that not all options are supported when using both `--staged --worktree`.

While "[`git restore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67076b85b8f82c751fe634abb112139d6e32a5f1/Documentation/git-restore.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore))</sup> supports options like `--ours` that are only meaningful during a conflicted merge, but these options are only meaningful when updating the working tree files.
These options are marked to be incompatible when both "`--staged`" and "`--worktree`" are in effect.

See [commit ee8a888](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee8a88826af1137f0b192caa39b016032ac96af2) (26 Feb 2023) by [Andy Koppe (`akoppe`)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/akoppe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 67076b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67076b85b8f82c751fe634abb112139d6e32a5f1), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`restore`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee8a88826af1137f0b192caa39b016032ac96af2): fault `--staged --worktree` with merge opts
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andy Koppe</sup>

> The 'restore' command already rejects the `--merge`, `--conflict`, `--ours` and `--theirs` options when combined with `--staged`, but accepts them when `--worktree` is added as well.
>
> Unfortunately that doesn't appear to do anything useful.
> The `--ours` and `--theirs` options seem to be ignored when both `--staged` and `--worktree` are given, whereas with `--merge` or `--conflict`, the command has the same effect as if the `--staged` option wasn't present.
>
> So reject those options with '`--staged --worktree`' as well, using `opts->accept_ref` to distinguish restore from checkout.
>
> Add test for both '`--staged`' and '`--staged --worktree`'.

Comment: Didn't know about `--worktree`. Now I can discard staged changes with a single `git restore --staged --worktree FILE`, instead of 2-step `git restore --staged FILE`+`git checkout FILE`. +1 for that!

Comment: @DarrenNg Exactly. The `git checkout` command should not be needed much anymore. Short version: `git restore -SW -- aFile`

Comment: hooray short ver!