# Can I revert to a previous version of just one file even if I git added all files before a commit?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-revert

Can I revert to a previous version of just one file even if I git added all files before a commit?

So, this is what I did:
`git add .` then `git commit -m "my changes"` then `git push`

So there have been many other git add . and commits between `"my changes"` and the current head.

Is it possible to revert back to `"my changes"` state for only one file even though I git added several files(`git add .`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire worry in your question is based on a total misconception of what Git is.

*Every* commit contains *all* the files. They are all snapshots of the *entire* project. `git add` just tells Git what files from the working tree to notice in particular for the next commit, but whether you include a file explicitly by saying `git add` or not before a *particular* commit, if that file is in a *previous* commit, it is in *every* commit thereafter.

So your saying `git add .` is totally irrelevant to anything.

The question becomes simply whether you can restore the state of a file. And the answer is yes, of course; every commit contains all the files, so just find a commit where you like the state of that particular file and extract it:

```
git restore --source=<thatCommitSHA> -- thatFile
```

Now `git add` that file (and anything else you feel like) and commit.

Comment: Docs are here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I do not understand why someone downvoted my question. Anyway, I am still confused. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005636/9953550) they are saying `git-restore is a tool to revert non-commited changes. Non-commited changes are: a) changes in your working copy, or b) content in your index (a.k.a. staging area).` I think what I was asking is how to revert to a previous version if the changes have been commited. If I am reverting to a previous commit, can I revert just for one file even though the commit contained several files?

Comment: Well, I really don't care what some other answer says. My answer says what _my_ answer says, and if you don't believe it, read the docs. I've answered the question and I stand by my answer. Try doing what I said.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thank you for your help. The reason I linked that answer is because I easily understand what they are saying. I am honestly still a bit confused. I find the docs to be a bit cryptic that is why I ask here.

Comment: Well, they can certainly be cryptic. Nevertheless it's worth learning to read them. The docs say of `git restore`: "Restore specified paths in the working tree with some contents from a restore source... `--source=<tree>`
Restore the working tree files with the content from the given tree. It is common to specify the source tree by naming a commit." So this tells you that restoring a file from a commit is _exactly_ the kind of thing this command can do.